# javascript pop up and block screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div pop up window which appears on button click event. I want to disable the screen when the pop up is shown to the user and enable again when user closes the pop up by escape key or close button on div, like a regular dialog box. How can I do this by java script.

Comment: The behavior you're looking for is called 'modal'. Doing a search on 'Javascript dialog modal' should turn up a result you need.

Comment: tried nothing till, I wasn't aware of term dialog model so many solutions on internet for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "cover" element that covers the screen preventing input from the user, except with whatever is on top (or inside) the cover.

`$('#button').click(function() { $('body').append('<div class="cover"></div>'); } );`

`.cover { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }`

You then assign events to the cover so when the user clicks it or presses a specific key, the cover is hidden.

`$('.cover').click(function() { $(this).hide(); });`

I highly recommend using a modal plugin/script, as doing it yourself requires significant effort and is time consuming (trust me).

Comment: Would you really append an element to `document`? Do you mean `"body"`? Also, it's better to capture a click on `document` to hide the modal, and simply stop click events on the modal from propagating beyond it.

Comment: Edited to append to `body` instead. Why is it better to capture the event on the document?

Comment: It's a fool-proof way of detecting any outside of the modal click interactions. It doesn't rely on CSS being used to create a large clickable area.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI makes your life easier.
Have a look at [jquery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery dialog and use the attribute `modal:true`

```
$("#fileuploadfun").dialog({ modal: true });
```

If you use `modal:false` then you can click on background